# When to use a namespace and when not to?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm a bit confused about when I have to specify the full path and when not. For example, `store: "Front"` just works without using the namespace:

```
Ext.define "App.Front"
    extend: "Ext.navigation.View"

    config:
        items:
            store: "Front"
```

But here using just `model: "Front"` wouldn't work:

```
Ext.define "App.store.Front"
    extend: "Ext.data.Store"

    config:
        model: "App.model.Front"
```

Everything is defined in my `app.js` (`models: [...]`, etc.), though. Where's the golden rule?

Comment: Does it require the full namespace when it invokes the "loader", where as an already loaded class is fine to use the "alias", have you tried adding the model as a requires in the app.js?

Comment: Interesting thought, I'll try that and let you know...

Answer (score 0):

Good question. As you correctly pointed out you require full path for the model but only store id is enough for a list or any such component that requires a store. As far as I know there is no well defined golden rule though in most cases you would not have to specify the full path. Yea I know Sencha kinda dropped the ball on this one.